# button assigned to scope variable in controller and binded to html with expression now i am clicking button not called function , how can do it?

Tags: angularjs

scope.html = " {{data}} ".Here {{data}} expression not working and when clicked button getUserDetails function not calling. how can i do this please help me.

I tried code

```
    html
    ----
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <form>
         <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
         <input type="button" ng-click="sayName(user.name);" value="sayName"/>
      </form>
       <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></span>
    </div>

    script
    -----
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.sayName = function(data){
     $scope.html = "<div><button ng-click='getUserDetails('"+data+")'> {{data}}</button></div>";
     }
     $scope.getUserDetails = function(data){
     alert(data)
     }
   }
```

I added [code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10153/) can see once please

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? See updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wboxqqu0/3/

```
html
----
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form>
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
     <input type="button" ng-click="sayName(user.name);" value="sayName"/>
  </form>
   <div ng-repeat="name in data track by $index"><button ng-show="name.length > 0" ng-click='getUserDetails(name)'> {{name}}</button>
</div>

script
-----
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.data=[];
 $scope.sayName = function(data){
 $scope.data.push(data);
 }
 $scope.getUserDetails = function(data){
 alert(data)
 }
}
```

Comment: input box I enter name like 'clickme1" submited button output I am seeing clickme1 button. next I entered input like 'clickme2'  clicked sayname button now i am seeing outlike 'clickme2'  button but i am not seeing first 'clickme1' click me button , how many times user enter that many button need to be visible. how can i do please help me?

Comment: please help me garethb?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="name in data"><button ng-show="name.length > 0" ng-click='getUserDetails(name)'> {{name}}</button></div> i kept in my practice project. in brower insept i am seeing code like this <!-- ngRepeat: name in gIn --> why?

Comment: Thats just Angular. I think you need a better understanding of Angular if you are going to try to use it. This site is great for people starting out http://www.learn-angular.org/

Comment: please help me garethb

Comment: <!-- ngRepeat: name in data-->  related information not there in http://www.learn-angular.org/, can you help me please

Comment: Thank you@garethb

Comment: Thats generated by Angular. Angular will add bits to your html that it needs to run. If you don't want this in your html, choose something other than Angular.